# Scrapy not returning data but instead a JSON error

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the artists from a site, and them scrape the artists songs and duration , however I keep getting an error and not sure what is causing this error.

Here's what I have tried:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class LyricalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lyrical'
    
    artists = [0, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K',
    'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

    start_urls = []
    for art in artists:
        start_urls.append(f'https://www.lyrics.com/artists/{art}')
    
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url, 
                callback = self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        container = response.xpath("//table[@class='tdata']//tbody//tr")
        for artists in container:
            links = artists.xpath("(.//a)[position() mod 2 = 1]//@href").get()
            yield response.follow(
                url = response.urljoin(links),
                callback = self.parse_artists
            )

    def parse_artists(self, response):
        table = response.xpath("//div[@class='tdata-ext']//table")
        for items in table:
            yield {
                'songs':items.xpath("(.//td)[position() mod 2=1]//text()"),
                'duration':items.xpath("(.//td)[position() mod 2=0]/text()")
            }
process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings = {
        'FEED_URI':'artists.jl',
        'FEED_FORMAT':'jsonlines'
    }
)
process.crawl(LyricalSpider)
process.start()
```

> TypeError: Object of type Selector is not JSON serializable
> 2022-01-23 14:50:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.lyrics.com/artist/H-monroy/2138107522>](https://www.lyrics.com/artist/H-monroy/2138107522%3E) (referer: https://www.lyrics.com/artists/H)
> 2022-01-23 14:50:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.lyrics.com/artist/U-God/278759>](https://www.lyrics.com/artist/U-God/278759%3E) (referer: https://www.lyrics.com/artists/U)

Comment: Try adding `.get()` where you yield songs/duration?

Comment: @JonClements That did the trick! I wish they would return a string mentioning to add this in when the error occurs. But I know now that may be causing an error like this for next time